# How can run my web application in tomcat with a different user than tomcat?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, sudo, processbuilder

What Ian wanted to do is run some external program or command from my WEB application (.sh, .pl even use directly ProcessBuilder or Runtime)

I achived to run the program or commands in my server, but the problem is that all of then are running as tomcat user. Then, for instance when I try to use ssh with public key I need to do a sudo -u "user" and then run the program or command. But unfortunatelly, I dont know why, it deesn't work.

After three days of troubleshooting, prof&error and google it, I'm thinking to run my application or procces wit a diferent user, thus avoid to use sudo command.

Then, I would like to know if somebody could tell me how I can do it or if there is any other best way to do that.

Comment: Just create a suitable Tomcat home for this other user. It's not very hard to do, and docs abound about it.

Comment: I don't think that's what is asked; I believe he wants to run Tomcat as user 'A' but run a process from within that Tomcat environment as user 'B'. And I don't think you really can do that without sudo; I mean that's what the command is for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647898/is-there-a-way-to-run-tomcat-as-a-different-user-and-group-on-rhel this can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Finally what I've done is to exacute my ssh throught [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthPubKey.java.html) and public key authentication. On this way I dont need to use sudo command since I can point out my user and private key. Oviously it's not run tomcat with different user but it fix my problem.